# How to substitute and matrix into a functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have $f(x)=2*x_1 +x_2$ 
how to find
$f(m*x)$ if m is a matrix 
$m=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: What is $f$? What is $\hat{x}$ for?

Comment: There was a mistake I correct it, thanks

Comment: Can you find $y = mx$? After that you can just compute $f(y) = 2y_1+y_2$.

Comment: Also posted as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424995/how-to-substitute-and-matrix-into-a-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  guess  from  your  question  that  $x=(x_{1},x_{2})^{t}$

Then ,$$f(x)=f(x_{1},x_{2})=2x_{1}+x_{2}$$
 Multiplying  $(x)$  with  the  given  matrix  $m$ . $$m*x=(x_{1}+2x_{2} , 3x_{1}+x_{2})^{t}$$ Then $$f(m*x)=f(x_{1}+2x_{2} , 3x_{1}+x_{2})$$$$=2(x_{1}+2x_{2})+(3x_{1}+x_{2})$$ $$=5(x_{1}+x_{2})$$

Hope  this  helps.

Feel  free  to  correct  me  if  I  got  the  question  wrong.

Comment: I think that is it, Thank you.